# How to create weighted lines from all point attributes to one point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, climate

The idea is that I want to show the relative financial contribution from various banks to an industrial project. So, for example, I have the coordinates of bank headquarters all around southeast Asia (orange points), each one of which has invested in a coal project (Java 9&10, red star). The points are all in the screenshot below.

[image: I've just drawn these lines, but I'm hoping to make something automatic based on the attributes, and where the line thickness is weighted based on the "Financier's total share" field (and with MapTips so you'll be able to hover and see... and ideally with the lines offset from one another so there's not overlap).]

Using graduated point sizes works as a way to show relative contribution but I'd like to make it more explicit, to show the *flows* of money, like what is in [this diagramme](https://gofossilfree.org/east-asia/visualization/), except in QGIS.

I have tried RT QSpider and Points2one plugins but can't get them to work.

[image: The attribute table]

Comment: This might get you started: https://anitagraser.com/2019/05/04/flow-maps-in-qgis-no-plugins-needed/

Comment: Thanks so much Matt! You're right, she's made exactly what I'm interested in. I've followed her comments as well as asked the person she mentions for his original dataset. I'm running into a bit of a roadblock (which some commenters on the blog also struggled with I think), interested if you could help potentially?:

I've created the non-spatial layer ("edges", exact same format to hers), and I already had the spatial "nodes" layer, as in the screenshot above. I've added an index column ("ID"), but when I used the same SQL query as her I get back "Referenced table nodes in query not found!"